# Cloud Foundry switch-space' is not a registered command

Tags: cloud, cloud-foundry, paas

I'm trying to run the command `cf switch-space` to switch between my Cloud Foundry accounts. Any suggestion why I have this issue ?

```
cf switch-space 
'switch-space' is not a registered command. See 'cf help -a'
```

**INFO**

```
$ cf -v
cf version 6.32.0+0191c33d9.2017-09-26
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it’s not a stock cf cli command. If you want to switch to a new org and space on the same foundation, use `cf target`.

If you want to save authentication and targets for multiple targets, I suggest using the `targets` plugin, found here: https://github.com/guidowb/cf-targets-plugin. It's also listed on https://plugins.cloudfoundry.org. Just search for `Targets`.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you want to do this within the same Org ,you can switch beetween spaces like this

`cf t -s <the-name-of-your-space>`

or login again to a different space

`cf login -a <endpoint> -u <user> -o <org> -s <space>`